# Changing SESSION variable after click

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to make a button on my website that switch  all images on the page to anothers . How can I do it if all the paths to the images are on the MySQL database ? I was thinking about changing SESSION value but I dont know if its the best solution in that case .

Its button to switch all images for colorblind people .

```
//CONNECT TO DB
<?php

 $_SESSION['mode']="normal";

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=shareboard', 'root', '');
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT path FROM images ");
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll();

?>

> 

//PRINTING IMAGE FROM DB

 <div class="sticky">
       <img src="<?php echo ROOT_PATH; print_r($result[46]['path']); ?>"  alt="daltonicon" title="Change contrast" style="position: fixed;
    top: 13px;
    right: 0;
    width: 35px;
    z-index: 1;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid black;">

      </div>
```

Comment: What have you tried?  This is a complex thing to do - show your code attempts, etc.

Comment: I have another column with  modified images and i dont know how to switched it  after  button click

Comment: Do you mean something like `pagination`? If you don't want the page to refresh then `pagination` with `AJAX`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use ajax to call another php page which will either return the url's to repopulate (and then you will need to process them with java to rebuild the element), or directly return the HTML and then use .innerHTML to update like so:

```
function updateStuff() {
    var userID = "id";
    var blah = "blah";
    var SendInfo= { "yourparam":userID,
                    "yourparam2":blah };

    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'https://whatever.com',
            data: SendInfo,
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
            traditional: true,
            success: function (data) {
                document.getElementById("yourelement").innerHTML = data;
            }
    });
}
```

Alternative solution is to get all the URL's at once and store them as a java array \ json object, then build all of the elements client side.

Comment: Thanks !  I figure it out  like you write and it works .

Comment: Awesome glad to help!  Would you mind marking this as the answer?